# Calculating the average number of files per folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shebang

so I'm writing a shell script that will count the average amount of files in a user-selected folder

I'm just not really sure, how to pull this off.

First things first, we gotta set user folder selection

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script for folder info
#-------------------------------------------
WANTEDFOLDER=$PWD
cd
cd $1 #Go into the folder (first argument)
$WANTEDFOLDER/folderinfo.sh
# ------------------------------------------
echo "Selected directory: $PWD"
```

I added few more commands of similar fashion, but those are working so for sake of readability I won't add them here.

So I was wondering, how could I possibly calculate the Average Number of Files located inside the Folders of a specified directory.

For better understanding of this, let's set up an example directory of

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ cd testdir
$ mkdir 1
$ mkdir 2
$ mkdir 3
$ cd 1
$ echo "hello" > wow.txt
$ cd ..
$ cd 2
$ echo "World"; > file.c
$ echo "file number 2" > twoinone.tex
$ cd ..
$ cd 3
$ echo "zzz" > z.txt
$ echo "zz2" > z2.txt
$ echo "zz3" ? z3.txt
```

Alright, so after this for better illustration, the folders look something like this

So first things first, we'll do `find . -type f`

This should print the following results

> ./1/wow.txt
>   ./2/file.c
>   ./2/twoinone.tex
>   ./3/z.txt
>   ./3/z2.txt
>   ./3/z3.txt

Now we've got 1 file in directory 1, 2 in 2 and 3 in 3. 
So to count the average it is (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 which results in 2.

This could be also written into an algorhitm of

(number of all unique files)/(number of all unique directories)

One thing is calculating this in your head and the other in actual shell script.

So in other words, I need to somehow transform into script some way, where it will count the number of files in a specific folder, store it, count all of them together and then in the end divide it by amount of unique directories.

So to get the amount of directories, we'll have to do `find . -type d | wc -l`

To get the amount of files, is quite simple. we'll just use the `find . -type f | wc -l`

What I however don't know is, how can I store these two values inside a variable and then divide them through one another

Moreover, I'd ideally prefer to format the code in a way for a specific line

eg. `echo "Average Number of files: $(find . -type f | wc -l (somehow divide) find . -type d | wc -l)"`

Any idea how to pull this feat off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
echo $(( $(find . -type f | wc -l) / $(find . -type d | wc -l) ))
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and working solution.

Didn't realise I could simply use arthimetical expression for two separate commands

Comment: It is the `$((..))` which is allowing you to do arithmetic. Note that it is only INTEGER arithmetic, so if you have 5 files in 2 directories, it is going to tell you 2 not 2.5 as the average.

Comment: Very true. If you are expecting non int results you can use `dc` or `awk` to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Is it really necessary to obtain a floating point estimate of the average number of files across all directories? But you asked the question, so there is at least a current need to address this.

```
#!/bin/bash

NumFiles=0

#Loop over all directories in the current location and count the files in each directory
DirCount=0
for d in */
do
        FilesInDir=$(\ls -A $d|wc -l)
        echo "Number of files in directory $d is $FilesInDir"
        NumFiles=$(($NumFiles+$FilesInDir))
        DirCount=$(($DirCount + 1))
done

echo Final number of directories: $DirCount
echo Total files in directories: $NumFiles

if [ $DirCount -gt 0 ]; then
        AvgFiles=$(echo "$NumFiles/$DirCount" | bc -l)
        echo $AvgFiles
fi
```